# Webapp - Custom Progressbar

Tags: java, javascript, user-interface, gwt

I need to implement a custom progressbar in my web application. I'm using Smartgwt to build the app UI.
The progressbar should be similar to (but not exactly):
[image: progressbar]

The progressbar should be dynamic (red and green marks according to a given parameters).

What should be the right technology to implement such a progressbar? should I do it using Smartgwt Composite extension? using javascript?

thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it easily using Javascript and CSS.

I'll assume the following components:

```
bar_container.png (481x36) - this is the empty grey background
bar_content.png (481x36) - this is the colored bar the starts with red and end with green
red_marker.png (20x36)
green_marker.png (20x36)
```

What you need to do is this:

```
<style>

    .container {
        position: absolute;
        width: 481px;
        height: 36px;
    }

    .content {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        background-image: url(bar_content.png);
        clip:rect(0px, 0px, 36px, 0px); /* modify the second value to adjust width */
    }

    .translucent {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .marker {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px; /* or where-ever it should be to fit */
        top: 0px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 36px;
    }

    .red {
        background-image: url(red_marker.png);
    }

    .green {
        background-image: url(green_marker.png);
    }

</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <div class="marker red">
    </div>
    <div class="content translucent">
    </div>
    <div class="marker green">
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    function setProgressBar(red, green) {  // red and green are values between 0 and 1
        document.querySelector(".content").style.clip = "rect(0px, " + (red * 481) + "px, 36px, 0px)";
        document.querySelector(".translucent").style.clip = "rect(0px, " + (green * 481) + "px, 36px, 0px)";
        document.querySelector(".red").style.left = (red * 481 - 10) + "px";
        document.querySelector(".green").style.left = (green * 481 - 10) + "px";
    }

</script>
```

You will need to adjust the values.

A better solution would be to wrap all that in a Javascript function so that it can be reused.

Comment: solved it using smartgwt extension. thanks.